# HTML input submit button is not working?What to do?

Tags: html, css, forms

I want to open another html file (in my browser). After filling all details, button "Sign me up!" is clicked, then my thanks page (MyLanding_ThanksPage.html) should be opened. But it is not opening. what is wrong here?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 
 <title>Startup Page</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="MyLandingPage.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Varela+Round&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>

 <form>

<h1>Welcome to the Landing Page</h1>

<h3>We're a start-up that changes world</h3>

<p id="p1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

<h3>Sign up for our upcoming launch!</h3>

<form class="signin" href="MyLanding_ThanksPage.html">

<label id="fname">First Name:</label>
<input id="fname" type="text" required="">

<br>

<label id="lname">Last Name:</label>
<input id="lname" type="text" required="">

<br>

<label id="email">Email:</label>
<span><input id="email" type="email" required=""></span>

<br>

<button class="signin">Sigh me up!</button>
<a href="MyLanding_ThanksPage.html">Sign me up!</a>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the [`form`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form) element does not have an `href` attribute. You need the `action` attribut to submit the form (preferably pointing to a server side script otherwise your input just will be lost when pointing to a html file)

Comment: He have two open form tag one of that have href.

Answer (score 1):

The form element does not have a `href` attribute. You can use `action` attribute for redirect to thanks page. `button element` use `type="submit"` attribute for submit this form
this is example:

```
<form class="signin" action="MyLanding_ThanksPage.php">
...
<button class="signing" type="submit">Sigh me up!</button>
</form>
</form>
```